# Tailcall parameter in Expression.Lambda

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, lambda, expression-trees

What is the reason behind giving a parameter for tailcall optimization in

```
Expression.Lambda(Expression body,bool tailcall,
IEnumerable<ParameterExpression> Parameters)
```

As long as it is not going affect the result why do we explicitly need to specify  a value for it.And i feel it is always better to have tailcall optimization. Do you have different thought on this

Comment: Ashley: It can be very hard to debug without a complete stack trace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The design is kinda funny.

Passing `true` for the `tailcall` parameter, will attempt to call method in a tail position as a tail call within the body of the lambda.

A tail position is where a method call is the expression being returned.

As for better, that is subjective.

- Tail calls tend to be always slower
- There are certain rules to follow (return types must match or be references)
- You have no stacktrace for debugging

Comment: Can you explain why it tend to be slower? Is this a .net issue with the implementation?

Comment: Seeing as how a tail call just does a "goto" rather than a function call, it should be faster because it doesn't have to push a whole bunch of data on the stack. This means that it saves the time of putting the data into memory but it also keeps the same stack memory areas in the local cache, saving some cache misses.

Comment: @CKoenig: On CLR 2 it the method call overhead is about 7 times of a normal call. This is has been found from benchmarking and personal experience from developing a language (IronScheme) that requires proper tail recursion.

Comment: @Gabe: What you are referring to is known as tail call elimination (TCE) where a tail call is converted into a `while(true) { ... }` loop. This is a very common optimization with the presence of tail calls.

Comment: @Ashley John: A tail call pops the stack before the method is called. This why you can't get a stackoverflow exception with proper tail recursion.

Comment: @lappie - thanks for your reply. This is rather interesting, because I do a LOT of tailcalls in F# and it's somewhat sad to hear that this gives you additional performance issues. Normaly I don't have to care all to much about performance but I will keep this in mind

Comment: @CKoenig: Most languages using tail calls will apply TCE, as mentioned in my reply to Gabe. I am pretty sure F# applies it where it can, but there exists cases where TCE cannot applied, like mutually recursive functions (see the classic odd/even example). TCE does improve performance a lot, probably better than normal calls, also like Gabe mentioned.

Comment: There is a bit of history regarding this, check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2009/05/11/tail-call-improvements-in-net-framework-4.aspx for more info